# Displaying images from the selected folder

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I am developing a GUI which has a 2 buttons called 'Open Directory' which enables user to open the directiory of his/her choice. Note that this directory contains only images. As soon as the directory is selected, the first image from `list_of_images` will be displayed on the window.

There is another button called 'next'. If user presses this button then the next image from the `list_of_images` would be displayed on the window.

I have 3 images in the folder that means my `list_of_images = ['a.jpg', 'b.jpg', 'c.jpg']`

Now the problem I am facing is that when I press the button **next** then the next image is displayed but when I press it again, it should display the third image but it doesn't. What might be the issue in the code?

I will provide the code to reproduce the problem. But you would need to change the folder or create a folder called test_images on your machine.

```
# Import pyqt stuff
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

# Import DL stuff
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Import the python script generated by the Qt-Designer
from gui_firstdraft import Ui_main_window

# Import miscellaneous
import sys
import os

class mainProgram(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_main_window):


    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        # Inherit from the aforementioned class and set up the gui
        super(mainProgram, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


    def all_callbacks(self):

        # Open directory callback
        self.openDirectory_button.clicked.connect(self.open_directory_callback)

        # Next button callback
        self.next_button.clicked.connect(self.next_button_callback)



    def open_directory_callback(self):

        # Paths
        self._base_dir = os.getcwd()
        self._images_dir = os.path.join(self._base_dir, 'test_images')

        # Open a File Dialog and select the folder path
        dialog = QFileDialog()
        self._folder_path = dialog.getExistingDirectory(None, "Select Folder")

        # Get the list of images in the folder and read using matplotlib and print its shape
        self.list_of_images = os.listdir(self._folder_path)
        self.list_of_images = sorted(self.list_of_images)

        # Length of Images
        print('Number of Images in the selected folder: {}'.format(len(self.list_of_images)))
        input_img_raw_string = '{}\\{}'.format(self._images_dir, self.list_of_images[0])

        # Show the first Image in the same window. (self.label comes from the Ui_main_window class)
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(input_img_raw_string))
        self.label.show()
        

    def next_button_callback(self):
        
        # Total Images in List
        total_images = len(self.list_of_images)

        if self.list_of_images:
            try:
                for img in self.list_of_images:
                    self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('{}\\{}'.format(self._images_dir, img)))
                    self.label.show()
                    
            except ValueError as e:
                print('The selected folder does not contain any images')
    

                
def execute_pipeline():

    # Make an object of the class and execute it
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Make an object and call the functions
    annotationGui = mainProgram()
    annotationGui.all_callbacks()
    annotationGui.show()

    # Exit the window
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    execute_pipeline()
```

I suspect that it has something to do with the next_button_callback but I am not really sure what the problem is.

Comment: It looks like the next function will result in the last image in the list being displayed every time, since it loops over the list and re-sets the pixmap each iteration.

Comment: How do I change the loop? Any ideas?

Comment: You shouldn't be using a loop. Keep an index to the current image and increment to access the next one.

Comment: @alec, wouldn't indexing require a loop? I don't quite understand what you mean. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the purpose of the loop if the function is to show next image in the list. Keep a reference to the index of the current file that is shown. In `open_directory_callback` this will be set to 0. In `next_button_callback` it is incremented.

```
def open_directory_callback(self):

    # Paths
    self._base_dir = os.getcwd()
    self._images_dir = os.path.join(self._base_dir, 'test_images')

    # Open a File Dialog and select the folder path
    dialog = QFileDialog()
    self._folder_path = dialog.getExistingDirectory(None, "Select Folder")

    # Get the list of images in the folder and read using matplotlib and print its shape
    self.list_of_images = os.listdir(self._folder_path)
    self.list_of_images = sorted(self.list_of_images)

    # Length of Images
    print('Number of Images in the selected folder: {}'.format(len(self.list_of_images)))
    input_img_raw_string = '{}\\{}'.format(self._images_dir, self.list_of_images[0])

    # Show the first Image in the same window. (self.label comes from the Ui_main_window class)
    self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(input_img_raw_string))
    self.label.show()
    
    self.i = 0
    

def next_button_callback(self):
    
    # Total Images in List
    total_images = len(self.list_of_images)

    if self.list_of_images:
        try:
            self.i = (self.i + 1) % total_images
            img = self.list_of_images[self.i]
            self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('{}\\{}'.format(self._images_dir, img)))
            self.label.show()

        except ValueError as e:
            print('The selected folder does not contain any images')
```

Comment: Ahh, okay, now I understand what you mean. Thank You.